# Proving this subset is a real linear subspace of $V=\mathbb{C}^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to prove or disprove that the following set $$Q = \{v \in V: \langle v,v\rangle = 0\}$$ is a real linear subspace of $V = \mathbb{C}^3$. If Q is a subspace of V, then the following must be true: $$(i) 0 \in Q$$ $$(ii) \forall v_{1}, v_{2} \in Q, v_{1}+v_{2} \in Q$$ $$(iii) \forall v \in Q, \forall c \in \mathbb{R}, cv \in Q$$ It is trivial that $\langle 0,0\rangle$ = $0$, so $(i)$ is satisfied. I'm having trouble showing $(ii)$ is satisfied. I know $$\langle v_{1}+v_{2},v_{1}+v_{2}\rangle = \langle v_{1},v_{1}\rangle+\langle v_{1},v_{2}\rangle+\langle v_{2},v_{1}\rangle+\langle v_{2},v_{2}\rangle = \langle v_{1},v_{2}\rangle+\langle v_{2},v_{1}\rangle$$ because $v_{1}$ and $v_{2}$ are in $Q$. But I don't know what to infer about $\langle v_{1},v_{2}\rangle$ or $\langle v_{2},v_{1}\rangle$. I see that $(iii)$ is satisfied because $$\langle cv,cv\rangle=c^2\langle v,v\rangle=c^2(0)=0$$ Thank you for the help.

Comment: What's $\langle x, y\rangle$? The natural thing associated to that symbol on $\Bbb C^3$ is the hermitian product $x_1\overline y_1+x_2\overline y_2+x_3\overline y_3$, which appears not to be the case here.

Comment: The problem starts with a Hermitian form $\langle x,y\rangle$ on $V$.  For this part of the problem, I was thinking $\langle v,v\rangle$ is a Hermitian form too because the vectors in the subset are on $V$ too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By your calculation on $v_1,v_2\in V$, $$\langle v_1+v_2,v_1+v_2\rangle=\langle v_1,v_2\rangle +\langle v_2,v_1\rangle =2\Re\langle v_1,v_2\rangle$$ Therefore, under the assumption that $v_1,v_2\in V$, $v_1+v_2\in V$ if and only if $i\langle v_1,v_2\rangle\in \Bbb R$.

If, for $A^H=A$, we define $\Phi_A(x,y)= y^HAx$, that map is a hermitian product such that $\Phi_A(e_i,e_j)=A_{ij}$. Knowing this, the existence of two vectors $w,v$ such that $\Phi_A(w,w)=\Phi_A(v,v)=0$ and $i\Phi_A(v,w)\notin\Bbb R$ can be forced upon a generic $3\times 3$ hermitian matrix $A$. This provides hermitian products $\Phi$ such that $V_\Phi$ is not a real linear subspace.